# Oracle client appears to be transmitting all 4000 varchar characters for each row

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database that I connect to over a somewhat slow network link. In there, I have a simple table, similar to this one:

```
create table EMPLOYEES (
    employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(4000)
);
```

And I'm using a rather boring query to retrieve all rows from it:

```
select employee_id, first_name from EMPLOYEES
```

So far so good. However, I'd noticed that when I ask Toad to export all rows resulting from that query, it takes about 4 seconds. In my .NET application, it takes 130 seconds. After quite a bit of hacking, I've noticed that the longest value in the FIRST_NAME column is 50 characters long, so I've altered my query as follows:

```
select employee_id, substr(first_name, 1, 50) from EMPLOYEES
```

Now, it is very fast in both Toad and my C#/.NET program. I have tried this using both Microsoft's and Oracle's data provider libraries, with the same result.

What is going on here ? Is Oracle -- as I suspect -- really sending 4000 bytes for each row, leaving it up to the client to cut them down to the right length ? What's the point of "var" in "varchar", then ? Also, how is Toad getting around this problem, and how can I do the same thing ?

Comment: do you know what driver you are using? e.g. 32 bit thin driver

Comment: I am using the 64-bit Instant Client, but this also happens with the 32-bit client as far as I can tell.

Comment: The server is definitely ***not*** sending 4000 characters for each row.

Comment: TOAD only fetches the first 500 rows into its grids by default...  are you comparing apples to apples with the number of result rows?

Comment: Then why does the second query execute so much faster in my .NET application ?

Comment: @Randy: Yes I am; I am telling Toad to export all rows from that table -- all 14,000 of them -- to the clipboard. When I paste them into a text editor, I verify that all rows have been exported.

Comment: ok - so the difference appears to be in the 'export' of TOAD vs you program as opposed to the query time from the database. i'd examine your export code to see what it is doing.

Comment: one more thought - compare the timing to that same query executed in SQLPlus spooled to a file.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  What version of .Net?  Please provide some specifics here as Oracle's Data Provider is definitely faster than the Microsoft Provider(33 - 50 % in most of my tests).  Also note in the later versions of .Net Microsoft has deprecated their driver in favor of the Oracle one.

Comment: I would also be cautious of using a reader across a slow network for small data.  Is the example above just a simple example - or does the first name field represent something else?

Comment: @Randy: I tried it in SQL plus, got the same result as in C#, i.e. an order of magnitude slower than in Toad. Still, that's one more data point to consider...

Comment: @tsells: I am using .NET 3.5 (I'd love to use 4.x but I can't), Oracle 11g. I tried this using both Oracle's and Microsoft's libraries, with the same results.

Comment: @tsells: I am actually selecting several varchar2 columns in my real query, representing some metadata for my business objects, but I get the same kind of performance difference if I only select a single varchar2 column (no matter which one, they are all varchar2(4000)). What would you suggest I use instead of a reader for small data ?

Comment: If the data is small enough - use a DataAdapter and return a full data set.  If you are bringing all of the data back in one trip - this will limit your round trips to the server which usually helps in slower connections.  However - if you have really large amounts of data - this can also be an issue.  In that case it's best to fetch the large data fields on demand (for example you have a list - and drill into the list and the details are displayed).

Comment: @tsells: In this case, I have about 14,000 rows and I do need them all. In my real application, I open up a Reader, read all the rows from it, and concatenate the results into a List<MyBusinessObject> for use later. I'm not sure whether a DataAdapter would speed things up in this case -- isn't this basically what it is doing internally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Oracle is not sending 4,000 bytes.  Let's assume you really are spooling all records in Toad.  All Toad is doing is fetching the records and printing them to the grid on your screen?  What is your code doing?  The SQL could be running in the same time, but your code is doing some other processing that is adding the time.

To really know what is going on, you need to do one or two things.

First, do a SQLNet client trace.  If that doesn't provide the answer, you need to do a server trace for you session.

Comment: My code is doing this: while(reader.MoveNext()) { list.Add(reader.GetString(1)); }  And that's all. If my code was the culprit, then changing the query while keeping the code the same -- as I have done -- would not affect its speed.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the only way to know for sure what is happeneing is to trace the sessions and compare the trace files.